# Make Mixins work by looping through a class (prototype) properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I was using Coffeescript for a while now... something I was using all the time is mixins, which I get inspired from this [article](https://yanhan.github.io/posts/2013-12-23-coffeescript-mixins.html), here is the class I had with coffeescript:

```
class @Module

    @extend: (obj) ->

        for key, value of obj

            # will be available as class methods

            @[key] = value

        this


    @include: (obj) ->

        for key, value of obj

            # Assign properties to the prototype

            @::[key] = value # similar to this.prototype[key] = value

        this
```

The `include` class method copies an obj (basically another class) methods, and make them as instance method for the target class, while the `extend` method will make the obj methods as a class methods for the target class.

The usage of this class is simple:

```
class @TargetClass extends Module

    @include Class1::
    @extend Class2::

}
```

As am moving to ES6 syntax now, I am trying to convert that syntax to vanilla javascript, here is my Module class:

```
export class Module {

    static extend(obj) {

        for (let key in obj) {

            // will be available as class methods

            const value = obj[key];
            this[key] = value;
        }

        return this;
    }


    static include(obj) {

        for (let key in obj) {

            // Assign properties to the prototype

            const value = obj[key];
            this.prototype[key] = value;
        }

        return this;
    }
};
```

Then am trying to make the methods of Class1 available as instance methods in my TestClass:

Here is my Class1:

```
export Class1{
  tobe_mixed_func(){
    console.log("it should works");
  }
}
```

And here is my TestClass:

```
import { Module } from "./module"
import { Class1 } from "./class1"

class TestClass extends Module{
  static initClass(){
    this.include(Class1.prototype) // I also tried this.include(Class1) but doesn't work either
  }
}

TestClass.initClass();

TestClass.tobe_mixed_func(); //  TestClass.tobe_mixed_func is not a function
```

I get an error that `TestClass.tobe_mixed_func is not a function`, I tried to debug to see if my `Module.include` function is receiving an the `Class1` in the obj parameter, and it does! however the thing I noticed is the `for (let key in obj) {...}` part of my `Module.include` doesn't loop throw the class "keys" which in this case supposed to be "tobe_mixed_func"

I have put a `console.log(key)` to see the output like this:

```
static include(obj) {

  for (let key in obj) {

    console.log(key);

     const value = obj[key];
     this.prototype[key] = value;
  }

  return this;
}
```

But the For loop never get executed... Can someone see what I am missing?

Comment: is `tobe_mixed_func` supose to be static ?

Comment: @Nicolas No it's fine like that, the `tobe_mixed_func` is a function of `Class1` and the `Module.include` is supposed to loop through the properties of the `Class1` and copy that function to the target class `TestClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are not enumerable and thus not listed when you do `for..in`. You need `getOwnPropertyNames` to copy them over:

```js
function assignAll(target, source) {
    for (let p of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source))
        target[p] = source[p];
}


class Module {
    static extend(obj) {
        assignAll(this, obj);
    }

    static include(cls) {
        assignAll(this.prototype, cls.prototype);
    }
}


class Class1 {
    tobe_mixed_func() {
        console.log("it should work");
    }
}


class TestClass extends Module {
    static initClass() {
        this.include(Class1)
    }
}


TestClass.initClass();

let a = new TestClass();

a.tobe_mixed_func()
```

As to the better way, I'd define an ordinary function (not a method), like this

```
function mixin(target, ...sources) {
    for (let src of sources)
        for (let p of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src.prototype))
            target.prototype[p] = src.prototype[p];
    return target;
}
```

and then declare mixins like this

```
 class MyClass {
    ...
 }

 mixin(MyClass, SomeMixin, SomeOtherMixin)
```

or even

```
const MyClass = mixin(class {
   ...
}, SomeMixin, SomeOtherMixin)
```

Comment: Men you saved my day :D for the `extend` function I got an error saying `TypeError: "length" is read-only` so I changed the code in it to `assignAll(this, obj.prototype);` and it worked. You told me Functions are not enumerable, how that was working when I was using Coffeescript? and a last question: do you think this is a good way to do mixins or there is a better way? Am learning something new here, thank you.

Comment: for the `Module.extend` I am passing a class as argument, so yeah it should be `static extend(cls)` and `assignAll(this, obj.prototype);`

Comment: @medBouzid: no idea how CoffeeScript does that, maybe they use `getOwnProperties` under the hood.

Comment: @medBouzid: some ideas added to the post